How to filter a nested array at the projection stage?
I'm struggling to filter a nested array at the projection stage.
The actual match condition is more complicated, but this will do:
db.collection.insertMany([
  { "id": 0,
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [
            {id: "000", go: "Y"},
            {id: "001", go: "N"},
            {id: "002", go: "N"} ]}}]},
  { "id": 1,
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [
            {id: "100", go: "Y"},
            {id: "101", go: "Y"},
            {id: "102", go: "N"} ]}}]},
  {
    "id": 2,
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [
            {id: "200",go: "N"},
            {id: "201",go: "N"},
            {id: "202",go: "N"} ]}}]}
]);

db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: { "list_L1.obj_L1.list_L2.go": "Y"}}
]);

(Apologies if the format is weird - I'm trying to save vertical space)
This filters documents alright, but I've been asked to also keep only the matching elements of list_L2, producing something like this:
[
  { "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 0,
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [
            {id: "000", go: "Y"} ]}}},
  { "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 1,
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [
            {id: "100", go: "Y"},
            {id: "101", go: "Y"}} ]}}}
]

If the document only had list_L1 it wouldn't be hard, but I can't "see" the values two levels deep; this returns empty arrays:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: { "list_L1.obj_L1.list_L2.go": "Y"}},
  {$addFields: { "list_L1.obj_L1.list_L2": {
    $filter: {
      input: "$list_L1.obj_L1.list_L2",
      cond: { $eq: ["$$this.go","Y"] }}}}}
]);

[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "list_L1": [
      { "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [] }}]},
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "list_L1": [
      {
        "obj_L1": {
          "list_L2": [] }}]}
]

So how do I filter the inner array after matching what I want? Alternative, Icould remove the non-matching elements of all documents and then filter for non-empty, but I'm too new to this.

Refactor your schema if possible. Store the innermost array elements as individual documents will help you gain query simplicity and potential performance boost through indexing.
Nevertheless, for your current scenario, you can use $map to iterate through  list_L1 array. Chain up $mergeObjects and $filter to return only matched elements in list_L2
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "list_L1.obj_L1.list_L2.go": "Y"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "list_L1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$list_L1",
          "as": "ll1",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$ll1",
              {
                "obj_L1": {
                  "list_L2": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$ll1.obj_L1.list_L2",
                      "as": "ll2",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                          "Y",
                          "$$ll2.go"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thanks, this works well.
I still don't understand why I can't filter list_L2 from the top but I can within the mapped $$ll1.
I also wonder if there's a way to filter the list first and then select the documents where it's not empty to avoid stating the condition twice.

As for refactoring, the inner elements are not shared between documents - would there still be gains from separating in two collections?

@arielCo The first $match is filtering according to your query on whole document level. As long as any of the array elements in list_L2 matches your query, whole document returns. Regarding filtering the list first and then select non-empty document, it would actually be suboptimal in performance, since you are processing the whole collection on field level projection. That makes you process some extra workload(i.e. those that do not have go=Y).

To refactor the schema, you may consider flattening the arrays like this

Ah, that's similar to $unwind on ..., list_L2 right? There's a lot of other data besides list_L1,, also several levels deep.

@arielCo The idea is to store the information at the level that you work most. That highly depends on your query pattern. If you work most on list_l2 level, store entries there as individual documents. You may resemble the structure with $unwind in an aggregation pipeline, but you won't be able to gain benefits from indexing.

Ouch, turns out I misread the schema and there's three levels: object-array-object-array-object-array(filtered). Does that mean that I have to alternate merge-map-merge-map-merge-filter? https://mongoplayground.net/p/i0U1tvAfwe4

@arielCo At this point the comments are getting long and messy. Please consider ask a new question and probably link back to this question to provide context, with your new sample data and corresponding, expected output.
